# how to edit the default view of sitefinity content types in cshtml file

Tags: sitefinity

I want to edit the default view of content type of NEWS in sitefinity ,bascially , i want to edit the cshtml file of the (NEWS) , but ,there is no such file in the built project .

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Resource Package? if so, you should be able to find the default views (List and Detail) under /ResourcePackages/Your_PACKAGE/Mvc/Views/News

If not, then you can find it in the Sitefinity backend under Design > Widget Templates

Comment: Let me rephrase, so i have created a widget , is it possible to put the widget under the "content" drop down menu in the backend dashboard ?

Comment: If you create a "widget", i.e. MVC Controller, then it should appear in the Toolbox in page edit mode. Maybe you meant that you created a new module using the Module Builder? In this case when the module is activated it should automatically appear in the menu under Content